# Elixir, error with postgresql: has invalid types for the connection

Tags: postgresql, elixir, ecto, semaphore-ci, postgrex

I'm getting the following issue:

```
ArgumentError{message: \"query %Postgrex.Query{columns: ["id", "name", "internal", "inserted_at", "updated_at"], name: "ecto_616034", param_formats: [:binary], param_oids: [25], param_types: [Postgrex.Extensions.Raw], ref: #Reference<0.0.1.107309>, result_formats: [:binary, :binary, :binary, :binary, :binary], result_oids: [23, 1043, 16, 1184, 1184], result_types: [Postgrex.Extensions.Int4, Postgrex.Extensions.Raw, Postgrex.Extensions.Bool, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.TimestampTZ, Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.TimestampTZ], statement: "SELECT r0.\"id\", r0.\"name\", r0.\"internal\", r0.\"inserted_at\", r0.\"updated_at\" FROM \"roles\" AS r0 WHERE (r0.\"name\" = $1)", types: {Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.TypeModule, 35356751}} has invalid types for the connection\"}", status: "error"}
```

My model schema is defined as following:

```
  schema "roles" do
    field :name, :string
    field :internal, :boolean
    many_to_many :user_organizations, User.Models.UserOrganization, join_through: "roles_users_organizations"
    many_to_many :sessions, User.Models.Session, join_through: "roles_sessions"

    timestamps()
  end
```

The tests are running ok on my local machine, but it happens every time on semaphoreci. I'm using docker-compose with the "postgis" image I have already tried with the "postgres" image with the same results.

Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which versions of `postgres` are you using on semaphore-ci and on your development machine?

Comment: The images I tried:

mdillon/postgis:9.1
postgres/9.6

On the local machine I'm using postgres.app with postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.6.1.

A full [log](https://hastebin.com/jisiyojexe.vbs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this occur in an umbrella App where the seeds.exs file for one project was mistakenly calling the Repo module for another app in the umbrella app.

So,

`cat app1/priv/repo/seeds.exs`

```
### Using The right Repo module ###
App1.Stuffs.query_stuff()
|> App1.Repo.one() # <== Should look like this -- Use App1.Repo module

### Using the wrong Repo module ###
App1.ThingStuffs.query_things() 
|> App2.Repo.one() # <== this was causing this error for me
```